# osCommerce: How do i change the 'quantity' field from only allowing numbers to all characters?

Tags: php, mysql, database, oscommerce

Is it something in MySQL or in the programming...cant figure it out!!

Answer (score 1):

in the mysql table the Quantity is set to an "int" data type. you can alter the table and change it to a "varchar" data type and that would allow you to have letters in there as well.

try something like this:

ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE quantity quantity VARCHAR(255);

Comment: You don't have to state the column name twice if you use MODIFY instead of CHANGE.